# sharepoint 2007 to 2010 list migration issue

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

i upgraded a sharepoint 2007 project to 2010 using database attach approach. all the customizations are working apart from custom list created through list definitions.

when i export 2007 list to a cab file and updated the systemdata.xml file to new schema re import back to 2010 it started working only that list

***old***

SchemaVersion Version="12.0.0.0" Build="12.0.10.0000" DatabaseVersion="44098" SiteVersion="0"

***new***

SchemaVersion Version="14.0.0.0" Build="14.0.4762.1000" DatabaseVersion="44098" SiteVersion="0"

i cant do this for all the list since site got hundreds of lists. how can i solve this issue

Comment: What exactly is the issue?  Is there an error, if so, what?  Did existing lists break?  Is it only new instance based on the template that are broken?

Comment: Ishan, could you please post the code for systedata.xml? Why don't you just upgrade the Product version from 3 to 4 in manifest.xml, if list templates are merely stp files?

Comment: You mentioned that this is a custom list. Do you have list definition for this list installed on the SP2010 farm?

Comment: @DaveWise the main issue is i can't edit any views as they are broken and get the generic sharepoint error. Also it is coming up with errors when i try to edit a record field and don't have any data in it eg the title field says "Title field value."

Comment: @FalakMahmood i got hundreds of list in my 2007 project cannot change one by one. the list are not created using stp files they all created from list definitions activated through feature.

Comment: @MaksymilianMulawa all the lists are created using list definitions. didn't change anything in the list schema (2007 solution) and installed the solution to 2010 as it is

Comment: @FalakMahmood sorry i didn't post the systemdata.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SystemData xmlns="urn:deployment-systemdata-schema">
    <SchemaVersion Version="12.0.10.0" Build="12.0.0.6665" DatabaseVersion="44098" SiteVersion="0" />
    <ManifestFiles>
        <ManifestFile Name="Manifest.xml" />
    </ManifestFiles>
    <SystemObjects>
        <SystemObject Id="781a749f-7020-4e27-8c41-26b849be1d5b" Type="Web" Url="/rdt" />
        <SystemObject Id="12570673-e69f-4313-8d78-2bd9ea408807" Type="List" Url="/rdt/_catalogs/users" />
    </SystemObjects>
</SystemData>

Comment: @DaveWise all the existing lists get break. something i noticed when i create a new list, it created properly but list have two title fields when i try to add new record, it says "One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields. "

Comment: Even custom lists upgrade properly so this really sounds like the issue is what it says it is - there is a feature that was installed and active on your 2007 farm that is not present on the 2010 farm.  Was there nothing in the preupgrade report about this?

Comment: i ran stsadm.exe -o preupgradecheck in my 2007 environment and backed up wss_content database and restore to 2010 and install all the solution as it is in 2007. ran the Test-SPContentDatabase no errors came.  after that i ran Mount-SPContentDatabase